# Need to sort rows together from two tables with the repeating row blanks

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have joined two tables using a union and join 
First table

```
FirstName  LastName
JOhn       Leigh
Adam       Jones

FirstName  LastName Contributorfirstname  Contributorlastname
JOhn       Leigh    John                 Leigh
JOhn       Leigh    MAry                 Leigh
Adam       Jones    Adam                 Jones
Adam       Jones    Kia                  Jones
```

need the below output

```
FirstName LastName      Contributorfirstname  Contributorlastname
John         Leigh       John                 Leigh
                         Mary                 Leigh
Adam         Jones       Adam                 Jones
                         Kia                  Jones
```

Comment: This type of transformation is usually (and best) done at the application layer.